# Where to find a "old" short comic about two friends finding a treasure map

Tags: story-identification, comics

Some years ago, I found on the internet (probably 9gag) a comic about two young friends that found/received a treasure map from an experienced adventurer. They both start to follow the map looking for the treasure itself encountering challenges/monsters on the way. When they finally come to the end, it’s empty!
Also in some point of the adventure the two friends argue and tear apart...

But in the end they re-encounter and discover that the adventure is the treasure itself, and they are experienced adventurers too and they give the map to other young friends.

The comic was in a RPGist environment with armors and swords, I can't remember well, but one of the main friends became a caster and the other a warrior, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure it was a comic? What you describe sounds almost exactly like the animated short film [*The Reward*](https://youtu.be/kkAYze6ae18), which was released online in 2013.

Comment: Exactly it, but I sincerely doesn't remember this as a film :) 
Anyway it's the correct answer!
Thank you!